# KeyListener is firering wrong Events

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I've written a simple KeyListener to recognize Arrow_Left/Right Events.
For some reason my Left-Key is firering 1 VK_LEFT pressed AND 1 VK_RIGHT Event (the Right-Arrow is working normaly)

Does this have to be a Hardware / KeyBoard problem (the arrow keys are working fine) or does one know how to fix this?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                //left
                System.out.println("leftPressed");
                keyLeftPressed = true;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                //right
                System.out.println("rightPressed");
                keyRightPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The console output on a leftClick is:
leftPressed
rightPressed

On a RightClick:
rightPressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 
                //left
                System.out.println("leftPressed");
                keyLeftPressed = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
                //right
                System.out.println("rightPressed");
                keyRightPressed = true;
                break;
        }
}
```

You use switch-case in the wrong way. The parenthesis aren't necessary, but you must add the break-statements.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot break statement on the case statement. If you did not break, the next case will be executed.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                //left
                System.out.println("leftPressed");
                keyLeftPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                //right
                System.out.println("rightPressed");
                keyRightPressed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```